# From input pass value to array and on replacing value in particular position in input replace at same place in array - JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

In input box i am typing for example 123 . it should store in array as 123 on keypress . If i replace instead of 2 by 5. So input box will have value 153 and same value must be passed to array that is 135. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: Can you share your attempt using `<>` and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="FirstValue" value="127" />
```

Js part:

```
/* we create empty array for us to manipulate */
var collection = [];
/* find the input box, wait for changes and we do the logic */
/* if list is empty, insert the value of that input box and if it already has on, */
/* then we pop that element and insert that value */
var text = $('#FirstValue').on('change', function(this.value){
  if(collection.length == 0) {
    collection.push(this.value);
  } else if(collection.length == 1){
    collection.pop();
    collection.push(this.value);
  }
}
```

You should go and search a bit about `jquery click change keyup events`. Quick articles would be good enough.